# Do all smartphone displays use same protocol (Mipi) for display driving?

Tags: display, smartphones

I thought of implementing a tool for capturing display signal over smarthphones with broken LCD. The idea is to open a smartphone and intercept the signal transimitted over the display using a Raspberry pi.

Then once signal captured, it can be transmitted over RDP/X11 protocol to a PC or another smartphone that exists on the same network that tool is connected upon.

The idea is to do stuff such as transfering files from broken devices to working ones or even converting smarphones to low-power pcs/servers. So far I found that [mipi](https://www.mipi.org/current-specifications) protocol is used for these type of devices but do ALL smartphone manufacturers use mipi protocol or not?

If not, how many protocols/standarts beyond mipi do exist, for display driving upon mobile devices, especially smartphones?

Comment: Intercepting MIPI signals is a non-trivial task, given the potential speed at which they can operate at (hundreds of MHz) and the chances of degrading the signal integrity by simply trying to probe these lines (because of the stub formed and additional bus capacitance added.

Comment: Some use LPDP (Low Power DataPort). There is a wide range even for MIPI because of the number of lanes and the different speeds. I've used MIPI at up to 1.4Gbps/lane with 2, 3 or 4 lanes. The phone also may not support bidirectional operation.

Comment: You would probably need a dedicated MIPI DSI receiver to decode that data and capture or convert it. Also remember that the total bandwidth for higher end screens is on the order of gigabits/second, possibly even more.

Comment: logic dictates that the title question can never have a `yes` answer